# transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f); rotates the 2D sprite, but not it's children

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to achieve firing from a 2D Player, attached the "spawn point" and made it a child of the Player, when I try to flip the sprite it works, but it does not flip the "spawn point" so when I turn left, my "spawn point" is still looking right, so when I shoot, the bullets go to the left, not to the right.

Full script:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{  
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.BoxCast(this.transform.position, new Vector2(0.4f, 0.1f), 0f, Vector2.down, groundCheckRadius, groundMask); //using this for a bigger and more accurate ground check
        isTouchingGround = (hit.collider != null) ? true : false;

        movementInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        CheckIfStuck(); //Checks if Mario is trying to walk into the wall and get stuck

        if (!isDead)
        {
            if ((playerRigidbody2D.velocity.x > 0 && !isFacingRight) || (playerRigidbody2D.velocity.x < 0 && isFacingRight))
            {
                playerAnimator.SetBool("turning", true);
            }
            else
            {
                playerAnimator.SetBool("turning", false);
            }

            float movementForceMultiplier = Mathf.Max(maxHorizontalSpeed - Mathf.Abs(playerRigidbody2D.velocity.x), 1);

            playerRigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(movementInput * movementForce * movementForceMultiplier, 0));

            playerRigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(playerRigidbody2D.velocity.x, -maxHorizontalSpeed, maxHorizontalSpeed), Mathf.Clamp(playerRigidbody2D.velocity.y, -maxVerticalSpeed, maxVerticalSpeed));

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                if (isTouchingGround)
                {
                    //Play Jump sound
                    if (!poweredUp)
                        audioSource.PlayOneShot(smallJumpSound);
                    else
                        audioSource.PlayOneShot(bigJumpSound);

                    isJumping = true;
                    playerRigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(playerRigidbody2D.velocity.x, jumpVelocity);
                    jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
                }
            }

            if (jumpTimeCounter > 0 && isJumping)
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
                {
                    jumpTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
                    {
                        playerRigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(playerRigidbody2D.velocity.x, jumpVelocity);
                    }
                }

            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                isJumping = false;
                jumpTimeCounter = 0;
            }

            playerAnimator.SetFloat("movementSpeed", Mathf.Abs(playerRigidbody2D.velocity.x));
            playerAnimator.SetBool("touchingGround", isTouchingGround);
        }

        if (movementInput > 0 && !isFacingRight)
        {
            FlipSprite();
        }
        else if (movementInput < 0 && isFacingRight)
        {
            FlipSprite();
        }

    }

    void FlipSprite()
    {
        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
        //Vector3 tempScale = transform.localScale;
        //tempScale.x *= -1;
        //transform.localScale = tempScale;
        transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
    }
}
```

Flip method:

```
void FlipSprite()
    {
        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
        //Vector3 tempScale = transform.localScale;
        //tempScale.x *= -1;
        //transform.localScale = tempScale;
        transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
    }
```

Comment: could you please reduce your code a bit to the neccesary? I can't find any `spawnpoint` or something similar in your code .. nor a method `shoot` or something that looks like it ...

Comment: I've deleted the code I think is not necessary. Because it does not shoot yet, all I want to do now is make sure the "spawn point" (child of the object Player) flips with the Player it self. Meaning that if I turn left, the child will also turn left and his x axis will point left and vice versa.

Comment: I wouldn't use this approach ... why not using somthing like e.g. `var spawnPosition = player.transform.position + transform.right * spawnDistance * (isFacingRight ? 1 : -1)` ?